# Разделение на две части css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не понимаю как разделить на две части и чтобы вторая ушла вниз.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По умолчанию в html всё и так идёт сверху вниз. Если у вас что-то идёт не сверху вниз, значит вы сами что-то где-то сломали, а значит покажите свой код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать максимальную ширину родителю или :

```
.class {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}

.left {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 2px solid green;
}

.block-1 {
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}

.block-2 {
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 2px solid hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Some text</div>
  <div class="right">Some text anover
    <div class="block-1">text</div>
    <div class="block-2">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```